# Why are Angular apps called Single-Page Applications when they still make use of hyperlinks to different pages?

Tags: angular, reactjs

This is a question I've found myself asking a number of times since starting to work with Angular. I've heard time after time that Angular is a great framework for developing Single-Page Applications.

Now to me, the idea that an application is single-page suggests to me that all aspects of the web app are loaded in a single page on the internet, at a single address. Surely then this would mean that an app loaded at http://myapp.com/index.html/ should never need to navigate away from index.html?

But in reality within Angular we use a RoutingModule which allows the user to navigate to different hyperlinks using html elements present within the webpage. The router enables access to other links such as contact.html, about.html etc.

So why exactly are SPAs named as such when they don't have a single page within their application, but actually have multiple?

The same can be said of Vue or React apps.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting confused, let me explain.

When you deploy an Angular application on a server, you deploy it on a specific domain. For the example, let's say `mydomain.com`.

When you build the angular application, it generates a single `index.html` file. This file imports all the required scripts to make your final application work.

From there, Angular's job is done. At this point, it's up to the server to manage the routing.

You have two different ways of the server managing the routing : the usual, known one, where the server manages the whole URL, and the [`HashLocationStrategy`](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles).

For the first one, **every request made to mydomain.com will be redirected to the root of the domain**.

That means that `mydomain.com/user/37` will redirect to `mydomain.com`, **and Angular will manage the routing back to the page**.

In the second solution, the URL becomes `mydomain.com/#/user/37`. In this case, only the root of the domain is exposed, **and everything after the pound sign will be managed by Angular**.

In both cases, you only have a **single `index.html` file** : this is why it's called a single page application.

In a SPA, the index file will display, thanks to JS, the content related to the request made by the user. In a non-SPA page, it's the server that displasy the required page.

Do not confuse the URL, which is simply a string, with a web application, which is a server, a client, a language ... And many more things.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, when you redirect  the links, a new page doesn't get loaded. Only the existing content changes dynamically through routing. It is basically a single page, on every route change, the content gets replaced.

Fore more info, read this [article](https://blog.angular-university.io/why-a-single-page-application-what-are-the-benefits-what-is-a-spa/)